# How can I speed up this plot manipulation? Why does Evaluate not help?

Tags: plotting, evaluation, performance-tuning

If I were able to "Save" the computed inverse function somewhere and then plot it, the manipulation would become faster. As I understand, Evaluate should do the job, but for some reason it does not. Why?

```
f[x_] := Sqrt[x]; c[x_] := x^2; g[x_] := c'[x]/f'[x];
x[gamma_, δ_, φ_, ρ_, mode_] := 
  InverseFunction[g][gamma/(1 - δ*φ*ρ)*mode];

Manipulate[
  Plot[
    {Evaluate@x[gamma, δ, φ, ρ, 1], 
     Evaluate@x[gamma, δ, φ, ρ, 2]},
    {gamma, 0, 10}, 
    PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {0, 10}}],

 {δ, 0, 1}, {φ, 0, 1}, {ρ, 0, 1}
]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the `Manipulate` as you wrote it, the `InverseFunction` has to be re-calculated every time the function `x` is called. To avoid this, define `x` with `Set` instead of `SetDelayed`:

```
f[x_] := Sqrt[x]; c[x_] := x^2; g[x_] := c'[x]/f'[x];

Clear[x];

Block[{gamma, δ, φ, ρ, mode},
  x[gamma_, δ_, φ_, ρ_, mode_] = 
    InverseFunction[g][gamma/(1 - δ*φ*ρ)*mode]
]

(*
==> ((gamma mode)/(1 - δ ρ φ))^(2/3)/(2 2^(
 1/3))
*)

Manipulate[
 Plot[{x[gamma, δ, φ, ρ, 1], 
   x[gamma, δ, φ, ρ, 2]}, {gamma, 0, 10}, 
  PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {0, 10}}], {δ, 0, 1}, {φ, 0,
   1}, {ρ, 0, 1}]
```

Then you can also leave out the `Evaluate` as I did above.

Comment: thanks for the reply. However, the `Manipulate` does not seem to work in your example..

Comment: Sorry, this was the Mathematica problem. I restarted it and it worked alright!

Comment: Jens, IMO you need to protect against the symbols used in `x` having values assigned.  I am going to wrap that definition in `Block`.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard What specific to this situation necessitates that Block be used?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard You're right, it's better to be safe than sorry. I could also have added the variables to the `Clear` statement. But using `Block` is more flexible because it leaves any previously assigned values for `δ, φ, ρ` etc. intact while at the same time preventing them from becoming part of the definition of `x`.

Comment: @Sjoerd Surely there is much code on this site, including my own, that assumes cleared Symbols to begin with.  However this is a *method* that without the `Block` or Formal Symbols is IMHO dangerous and should not be proposed without either the warning or the protection.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, by the way, is there a way to pre-evaluate the function for all possible parameters of manipulation (let's say over a fine grid) so that manipulation becomes instantaneous?

Comment: @P.Escondido Sorry, I forgot to reply until now.  You'd do well to ask that as a new, focused question.  There are a couple of tricks I can think of that might be useful but I don't have time at the moment and comments aren't the right venue anyway.

Answer (score 3):

`Evaluate` needs to be the top-most expression inside `Plot`.  As in, the code needs to look *exactly* like:

```
Plot[Evaluate[...], ...]
```

or else the call to `Evaluate` will be effectively ignored.

Comment: I implemented what you've suggested and `Manipulate` stopped working

Comment: Perhaps you need to restart Mathematica for some reason?  I'm using `Manipulate[Plot[Evaluate[{x[..., 1], x[..., 2]}],...],...]` without any problems.

Comment: Indeed, restart helped! Thanks! Is that common that Mathematica needs a restart to work properly?

Comment: It was probably working properly before, but you may have had some intermediate state (such as another definition for `x`) that was causing unexpected behavior.  This would have been difficult to track down online, so I suggested a restart.