# Plot manipulation too slow

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, performance-tuning

I tried manipulate simultaneously the plot of a function and its indefinite integral from 0. However, the evaluation is too slow and I believe that's not because of my computer hardware. Is there any way to optimize it?

```
f[x_] := (3/2) Sin[((2/10) x)^2];
i[y_] := Integrate[f[x], {x, 0, y}];
label1 = "f(x) = \!\(\*FractionBox[\(3\), \(2\)]\) \
sin(\!\(\*FractionBox[SuperscriptBox[\(x\), \(2\)], \(25\)]\))";
label2 = "\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[SubscriptBox[\(\[Integral]\), \(0\)], \
\(x\)]\) f(u) \[DifferentialD]u";

Manipulate[
 Plot[{f[a], i[a], 0 a}, {a, 0, x},
  PlotRange -> {{0, 15}, {-2, 8}}, 
  Filling -> {1 -> {3}, Axis},
  PlotLegends -> {label1, label2}],
            {x, 0.1, 15, .2}]
```

Comment: `i[a]` is being reintegrated at each time step. Try `With[{ia=i[a]}, Manipulate[..., {f[a], ia, ...] ]` instead. Works great for me.

Comment: Just worked fine!

Comment: You should also look through this for a more thorough discussion http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/28920/38205

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple solution to your problem is to integrate `f` just once before making a down-value (internal definition) of `i`. You can accomplish that by replacing `SetDelayed` ( `:=` ) in your definition of `i` with `Set` ( `=` ). With this approach, plotting `i` becomes a simple expression evaluation in the `Manipulate` rather than a symbolic integration each time you move the slider for `x`.

```
f[x_] := (3/2) Sin[((2/10) x)^2]
i[y_] = Integrate[f[x], {x, 0, y}];

Manipulate[
  Plot[{f[a], i[a], 0 a}, {a, 0, x}, PlotRange -> {{0, 15}, {-2, 8}}],
  {x, 0.1, 15, .2}]
```

[image: demo]